I wrote deactivate() instead of deactivate at the terminal prompt. How do I get back?
I wanted to deactivate virtual environment by command deactivate but accidentally wrote deactivate(). It then opened console with
function>

I typed some symbols and now, when I call command deactivate it tries to execute those symbols as command and obviously give error that there is no such command. I tried to type deactivate inside of it, but it didn't work.
How can I revert deactivate to its original behavior?

Just ctrl-C out of it.

What exactly works also depends on which shell you are using. Based on the described behavior, I'm guessing Zsh; please edit to fix if this is incorrect.

@tripleee it doesn't work. As to type of shell, I believe it is indeed Zsh (all errors starts with zsh: text of error)

@Nourless: “it doesn't work” is not an adequate problem description. Pressing Control-C will terminate bash’s or zsh’s prompt to continue a function definition. It is unlikely that did not work. If you wanted something else to work, such as closing a Terminal window or other behavior other than just ending the prompt for the function definition, you need to clearly describe what behavior you want and what behavior you observed. In that case, you should probably also specify what “virtual environment” you were using.

Too many close reasons to choose between: More for superuser than Stack Overflow, needs details, or was caused by a typo.

I guess you already managed to redefine deactivate. There is no easy way to get it back in the current shell; but just start a new one. I posted an answer with more details.

deactivate() starts a zsh function definition, and the prompt function just serves to remind you that you need to provide a zsh function definition. If you type Control-C, you abort the function definition and everything is back as before. If you type something else (for instance echo I messed it up), you are replacing the previous function definition by a new one. In this case, I suggest to open a new zsh instance.

When you wrote deactivate() you told the shell you are starting to define a function with this name. It's waiting for you to complete this, and will return to normal once you finish what you started.
You don't want to redefine deactivate, so probably break out of this with a simple ctrl-C.
If you already managed to redefine deactivate, there is no straightforward way to return it to its earlier definition, but don't worry; it won't stick, so just start a new shell (maybe exit the current shell, or leave it open if you still have unfinished business there).
This assumes you are using a Bourne-compatible shell like Zsh or Bash. They both happen to behave the same with regard to ctrl-C in this scenario.
When you activate a virtual environment, you basically change some settings in the currently running shell instance. All of those things are ephemeral and will go away once the shell exits.
Similarly, functions you define are local to the currently running shell instance, and won't carry over; to make a function permanent you have to put its definition in one of your shell's startup files.
